# 404 page not found error while publishing Angular project on Github pages

Tags: angular, github, angular-cli, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I'm trying to publish my Angular project https://github.com/KrishnaVeer7712/Reactive-and-Dynamic-Web-Page using Github pages at https://krishnaveer7712.github.io/Reactive-and-Dynamic-Web-Page/ but i'm getting error 404 Page not found.
It is working fine when i open my project on localhost.

Steps I've done:

`ng build --prod --base-href /Reactive-and-Dynamic-Web-Page/` works fine

`gh-pages -d dist`  (Published)

[image]

I don't know where i'm doing wrong , can anyone please tell me what could be the reason.

Comment: Check this official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples)

Comment: Check my post: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/angular-7-deploy-to-github-pages-images-assets-7704f3b2005c

Comment: @MiroslavMaksimovic Thank you for reply but script 'npm run build-and-deploy-gh-pages' not working, getting error : 'npm ERR! missing script: build-and-deploy-gh-pages'

Comment: You have to put this script inside your package json scripts array:
`"build-and-deploy-gh-pages": "ng build --prod --base-href ./ && npx ngh --dir dist/[reponame]"` or in terminal just run it  like this:

`ng build --prod --base-href ./ && npx ngh --dir dist/[reponame]`

Comment: There is a working repo at the end of the post: https://github.com/ngQuad/website/blob/develop/package.json

Answer (score 1):

maybe you must specify the directory of your build and not the dist directory

```
gh-pages -d dist/your_application_name
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: Thanks for replying but i already tried this too 'gh-pages -d dist/Reactive-and-Dynamic-Web-Page' (Published) but giving same error 404 page not found.

Comment: Hi, a possible solution to your problem is to specify the absolute url ( https://krishnaveer7712.github.io/Reactive-and-Dynamic-Web-Page/ in this case) in the base-href parameter when you build your application. For more information see this article,  https://medium.com/tech-insights/how-to-deploy-angular-apps-to-github-pages-gh-pages-896c4e10f9b4. Hope this can help yout.